# jQuery el.each() returns HTMLAnchorElement instead of elements instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, element, each

I have the following HTML scheme:

```
<section id="vids">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a data-reference="12345" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345" rel="external" target="_blank">
                <span>Video 14</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</section>
```

And the following JavaScript part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#vids a")); // Returns element instance collection

    $("#vids a").each(function(i, el) {
        console.log(this); // Returns HTMLAnchorElement instead of the element itself
        console.log(el); // Same here
        console.log(i); // Returns index
    });
});
```

I need to use the methods .removeAttr() and .attr(), but it does not work because .each() returns the elements prototype instead of its instance. Same problem on a simple for loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` refers to the DOM element. To use jQuery functionality on this element you need to wrap it in a jQuery object, ie: `$(this)`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#vids a")); // Returns element instance collection

    $("#vids a").each(function(i, el) {
        console.log($(this)); // Will return [Object object]
        console.log($(el)); // Same 

        var $el = $(this);
        $el.removeAttr("attribute").attr("foo", "bar");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `this` like so: `$(this)` to use it how you describe.

This is the expected behaviour as described in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, **so
>   the keyword this refers to the element**.